# How can I typeset determinants of Cramer's rule?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, matrices, cases

I want to typeset the determinants of the system

```
$\begin{cases}
a_1x+ b_1y = c_1,\\
a_2x+ b_2y = c_2.
\end{cases}$
```

I tried

```
$D=\left| \begin{matrix}
   {{a}_{1}} & {{b}_{1}}  \\
   {{a}_{2}} & {{b}_{2}}     
          \end{matrix} \right|
={{a}_{1}}{{b}_{2}}-{{a}_{2}}{{b}_{1}}$
```

and

```
$D_x=\Biggl| \begin{matrix}
   {{c}_{1}} & {{b}_{1}}  \\       
   {{c}_{2}} & {{b}_{2}}    
   \end{matrix}  \Biggr|
={{c}_{1}}{{b}_{2}}-{{c}_{2}}{{b}_{1}}$
```

I don't understand, I get

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Please explain exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not see a problem, except that the source can be simplified:

- Many pairs of curly braces can be removed, e.g.: `{a}` is equivalent to `\mathord{a}` and `a` that is already an ordinary atom.
- Package `amsmath` also provides environment `vmatrix`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  D = \begin{vmatrix}
        a_{1} & b_{1}  \\
        a_{2} & b_{2}  \\
      \end{vmatrix}
  = a_{1} b_{2} - a_{2} b_{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking for an environment suitable for determinants, there is `vmatrix` from `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\(D_x = \begin{vmatrix}
   c_{1} & b_{1}  \\
   c_{2} & b_{2}
\end{vmatrix} = c_{1} b_{2} - c_{2} b_{1}\)


\end{document}
```

[image]